# I can't get data-img-id from input file jQuery HTML, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, html

I've tried different ways but i get the first value always

HTML

```
 <i for="imgupload" class="material-icons imageUploadIcon">camera_alt</i>
    <input id="imgupload" type="file" data-img-id="0" accept="image/*" style="display: none;">

<i for="imgupload" class="material-icons imageUploadIcon">camera_alt</i>
    <input id="imgupload" type="file" data-img-id="1" accept="image/*" style="display: none;">

<i for="imgupload" class="material-icons imageUploadIcon">camera_alt</i>
    <input id="imgupload" type="file" data-img-id="2" accept="image/*" style="display: none;">

<i for="imgupload" class="material-icons imageUploadIcon">camera_alt</i>
    <input id="imgupload" type="file" data-img-id="3" accept="image/*" style="display: none;">


<i for="imgupload" class="material-icons imageUploadIcon">camera_alt</i>
    <input id="imgupload" type="file" data-img-id="4" accept="image/*" style="display: none;">
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
      $("#imgupload").on('click', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var imgid = $(this).data('img-id');
        console.log(imgid);
        var image = $('#imgupload')[0].files[0];
        var uid = <?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>;
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('image',image);
        fd.append('uid', uid);
        fd.append('imgid', imgid);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/usrIMG.php",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
      });
    });
```

console log prints 0 on every click

[Console log Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnS4Q.png)

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: @j08691 IDs are unique,  but the jquery $(this).data('img-id'); this always gets the first id which is 0

Comment: instead of ID you can use following things:
1. assign class and use $(".classname") to attach click event.
2. put all inputs in one div and use  $("#DIVID").find("input").on("click")

Comment: try `$(this).attr('data-img-id');`

Comment: You use the ID `imgupload` five times. How's that unique??

Comment: @MohanPrajapati console log i blank

Comment: @j08691 but then i should add five times jquery with differend IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic|Roboto+Mono:400,500|Material+Icons" />
      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      Icon for Image ID #0:
      <br>
      <i for="imgupload" data-img-id="0" class="material-icons imguploadicon">camera_alt</i>
      <hr>
      Icon for Image ID #1:
      <br>
      <i for="imgupload" data-img-id="1" class="material-icons imguploadicon">camera_alt</i>
      <hr>
      Icon for Image ID #2:
      <br>
      <i for="imgupload" data-img-id="2" class="material-icons imguploadicon">camera_alt</i>
      <hr>
      <input id="imgupload" type="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(".imguploadicon").on('click', function(){
            var readyflag = true;
                if (readyflag == true){
                var uid = <?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>;
                var imgid = $(this).data('img-id');
                console.log('the image id for this click is: ' + imgid);
                 $('#imgupload').click();
                 $("#imgupload").change(function (){
                   var filename = $(this).val();
                   console.log('the file name for the upload is: ' + filename + ' (img id: ' + imgid + ')');
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('image',image);
                    fd.append('uid', uid);
                    fd.append('imgid', imgid);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "php/usrIMG.php",
                        data: fd,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log("data was uploaded!");
                            readyflag = false;
                            imgid = '';
                            image = '';
                        }
                    });
                });
             }
         });

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Rather than trying to grab it off the input, call the function invoking the class of the trigger (in this case the icon) and pass the image id through there; you can call the click to the upload form shortly after (as seen in the example above); again it's conceptual (and a different approach) but works pretty good.

-- Modified code to wait for change on file field after we already got the img id; once the file field input is changed (file was selected) the AJAX will post the formdata to upload the contents of the created form. I've also added a boolean true/false check to ensure when we clear out the data for the next image that it won't trigger a false-positive upload of blank data; you'll see what I mean when you attempt to execute the script; give it a try.

Comment: Awesome! rock on

Comment: There is a problem now because ajax is not working on post jquery .on('click') neither .on('change')

Comment: Is it the same code snippet you put up in the question? Update it with your latest code pls

Comment: .on('click') it doesnt show me to choose an image only runs the php file, .on('change') it shows to choose an image but the ajax didn't post on php the php file is not fired.

Comment: Modified snippet, give it a try.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting id because you have hide the elements. try to remove one display:none and check.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/436281/`
```